# How do I calculate Voltage and Current in a combination circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

Specifically, I am confused on how to find the voltage of a parallel circuit if the resistor is in front of it. Do I use the original voltage source, or the Voltage of the parallel circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve this problem directly in one step. You will have to turn this entire circuit into a circuit with just one battery and one equivalent resistor, then unpack it step by step.

Notice that the two resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$ are in parallel with each other. You combined these two resistors together to find an equivalent resistor of $R_{12EQ}=1.71\Omega$.

At this point you have the three resistors ($R_3$, $R_4$, and $R_{12EQ}$) in series with a battery. If you find the current passing through this (series) circuit (by combining $R_3$, $R_4$, and $R_{12EQ}$ into a single $R_{EQ}$), you may then unpack this circuit to find the voltage across each of these three resistors ($R_3$, $R_4$, and $R_{12EQ}$) from Ohm's Law.

Specifically, find the voltage drop across $R_{12EQ}$, than ask yourself how will this voltage drop be related to the voltage drop across $R_1$ and the voltage drop across $R_2$.